# phpvideotoolkit class errors on xampp installed on windows server 2008

Tags: php, ffmpeg, xampp

find i m trying to convert sequence of images into a video. and for that i canme to know about the ffmpeg class.

the only wrapper class that i found is phpvideotoolkit but i m not able to work with it.

i installed phpvideotoolkit on xampp on my windows 2008 server . but it is throwing alor of errors

```
This example shows you how to extract a specific frame from a movie.


Notice: Undefined property: PHPVideoToolkit::$_tmb_directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpvideo\phpvideotoolkit.php5.php on line 869

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpvideo\phpvideotoolkit.php5.php on line 877
PHPVideoToolkit Error: Execute error. Output for file "C:\xampp\htdocs\phpvideo\examples\working\to-be-processed\MOV00007.3gp" was not found. No images were generated.

Notice: Undefined property: PHPVideoToolkit::$_tmb_directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpvideo\phpvideotoolkit.php5.php on line 869

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpvideo\phpvideotoolkit.php5.php on line 877
PHPVideoToolkit Error: Execute error. Output for file "C:\xampp\htdocs\phpvideo\examples\working\to-be-processed\Video000.3gp" was not found. No images were generated.

Notice: Undefined property: PHPVideoToolkit::$_tmb_directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpvideo\phpvideotoolkit.php5.php on line 869

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpvideo\phpvideotoolkit.php5.php on line 877
PHPVideoToolkit Error: Execute error. Output for file "C:\xampp\htdocs\phpvideo\examples\working\to-be-processed\cat.mpeg" was not found. No images were generated.
```

example

```
PHPVideoToolkit Error: Execute error. Output for file "C:\xampp\htdocs\phpvideo\examples\working\tmp\1336156630-4fa421d69357d\tmp_%d.jpg" was not found. Please check server write permissions and/or available codecs compiled with FFmpeg. You can check the encode decode availability by inspecting the output array from PHPVideoToolkit::getFFmpegInfo().
```

i m trying to make it work since last many hours but no luck

Also, for this code :

```
$srcFile = "test-mpeg.mpg";
$ffmpegObj = new ffmpeg_movie($srcFile);
```

i am gettign error that it cant file the file. i believe its something to do with permissions but i m not able to figure out

fpoen , fwrite , file_put_contents all are working fine without any permissions problems.

can anyone please guide me in the write direction. what do i need to do to make this phpvideotoolkit  work